# What is the reason this variable isn't printing?

Tags: python, variables, loops

This is a program that I am writing. I'm just wondering why my global variable `ABSDEV_SUM` isn't printing after the loop ends.

```
# python_fitness_function

import pandas as pd
import itertools


infile_path = "C:\\Users\\Tim\\Dropbox\\Lela.com_DrBx\\APR14_query_work\\"

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(infile_path + "mp_viewed_item_AGG_affiliate_item_TOP_10.csv", sep=',', index_col=True)


groups = df.groupby('Affiliate_ID')


df_cameta = groups.get_group("cameta")

cols = list(df_cameta.columns)

while 'Affiliate_ID' in cols:
    cols.remove('Affiliate_ID')

Motivator_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]

index = 0
ABSDEV_SUM = 0

for i in cols:
    column = df[i]
    AbsDev = sum(abs(pair[1] - pair[0]) for pair in itertools.combinations(column, 2))
    ABSDEV_SUM = ABSDEV_SUM + AbsDev
    print "Motivator_" + Motivator_list[index] + "_Mean_AbsDev"
    print AbsDev
    index += 1

print ABSDEV_SUM
```

Can anyone shed any light on this for me? Sorry if it seems a trivial step.

I'm getting this code when the loop terminates:

```
  File "~\APR14_query_work\python_fitness_function.py", line 37, in <module>
    print "Motivator_" + Motivator_list[index] + "_Mean_AbsDev"
IndexError: list index out of range
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

I think what is happening is it's going through one additional iteration of the loop, throwing the "out of range" error, then simply not printing because it terminates. I don't know if that's the case, it seems that way, but I cannot pinpoint why.

I've tried shuffling my lines around in the loop, to no avail.

Comment: Can you please show us full of your code?

Comment: Are you sure that `Motivator_list` is at least as long as `cols`?

Comment: No, you're getting that traceback *before* the loop terminates. That R2 unit has a bad motivator. I MEAN your `Motivator_list` doesn't have as many members in it as `cols`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indeed means that Python terminates the program because it detects an unrecoverable exception.

The problem is that the value in `index` is larger than the number of elements in `Motivator_list`.

(A typical problem is off-by-one -- you create an index just past the end of the list in the last iteration, perhaps because you started from 1 instead of 0?  In this case, though, it seems simply that `df_cameta.columns` contains more values than the twelve you have in `Motivator_list`. Maybe make the list longer? Or grow it dynamically as needed?)